# Recreate Fragment from parent Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I need to recreate a fragment from its parent Activity. The solutions I found were all 10 years old and in Java. Is there a neat way without too much boiler plate to implement something like this?

Like from Activity:

```
getFragments().recreate()
```

I have tried different solutions so far but have not been able to make it work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to recreate a fragment from its parent Activity.

Just replace it with a new instance:

```
fragmentManager.commit { replace(idOfFragmentToReplace, MyFragment.create(...)) }
```

Or you could [recreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#recreate()) the whole Activity.

Comment: Recreating an Activity preserves the arguments; you might want to include copying those over.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "include copying those over".

Comment: I meant that it would be good to include copying the existing arguments to the recreated fragment as part of the example code.

Comment: Ah. I didn't want to make assumptions about whether the OP's fragments took arguments or not, so I left the example with the placeholder block `MyFragment.create(...)` - the `...` being the arguments needed for the new fragment, if any.

Comment: Whether or not it takes arguments, though, copying over whatever is in `getArguments()` should be correct (you'll either copy nothing, or the arguments; either way, it's fine).  It also avoids the need to translate the arguments from the Fragment back into whatever format they use for the `create` call.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is in the host activity:

```
this.recreate();
```

I have various database queries in my fragments that are executed asyncronously. After a recreate(), all fragment pages are displayed with current data.